# Why is “c'est un” pronounced /sɛ tœ̃ /, but “c'est une” /sɛ tʃyn/?

Tags: prononciation, standard, phonétique

I'm learning French, and from what I've heard, it seems that:

- *c'est un* is pronounced /sɛ tœ̃ /, but
- *c'est une* is pronounced /sɛ tʃyn/,

with a /tʃ/ as in *cheese*. I heard this difference both in Duolingo and Forvo ([un](http://sv.forvo.com/word/c%27est_un/), [une](http://sv.forvo.com/word/c%27est_une/)).

Is this the case in standard Parisian dialect? Why does it happen, and when?

Comment: I don't hear /tʃ/ in that une forvo recording, btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR : this is not a standard pronunciation.** Even [@Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles) can't picture anyone pronouncing [tʃ] or [ts]<sup>[1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5824/why-is-cest-un-pronounced-s-toe-but-cest-une-s-tyn#comment9876_5826)</sup>.

In Français Standard, it should be [sɛtyn], [tʃ] is a common variant in Cajun French and in varieties of rural France, especially in informal speech. Québécois and Acadien use [ts], which is quite close and may be related.

As for *why*, I am not really sure, but I suspect it is a case of [mouillure](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouillure) or [palatalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization): it happens in many mothereses in French, and in some cases in informal speech that an occlusive consonant before a front vowel is palatalised as in [k]→[kʲ]

> *Qui c'est ce bébé ?* [kisesəbebe]

Can be pronounced [kʲisesəbebe] in motherese. I have been told by a Basque teacher that this palatalization can be mandatory in Basque when addressing relatives or close friends.

Then, as time goes by, this pronunciation can evolve to [kʃ] or [tʃ]. The same thing happened to the initial [k] Latin *cabalus*

[k] > [kʲ] > [tʲ] > [tʃ] > [ʃ]

which is how ***c**​abalus* became ***ch**​eval*.

Since Cajun, and in a lesser measure Québécois inherited more from informal French, it could be how [cɛtyn] became [cɛtʃyn].

Comment: Just to clarify: this is *not* a standard thing. I (mostly Parisian or thereabouts) can't picture anyone pronouncing [tʃ] or [ts].